# ARM PLD and offset

Tags: caching, assembly, arm

Good morning, I'm studying ARM assembly, Cortex A series. Reading the ARM documentation I found out this paper (Cortex A8, fast memcpy examples). My attention went to the PDL instruction, preloading into cache. I have read about it on the ARM manuals, but I still don't understand why the offset is in this way:

```
WordCopyPLD
      PLD [r1, #0x100]
      MOV r12, #16
WordCopyPLD1
      LDR r3, [r1], #4
      STR r3, [r0], #4
      SUBS r12, r12, #1
      BNE WordCopyPLD1
      SUBS r2, r2, #0x40
      BNE WordCopyPLD
```

Why the offset in this case is 128 byte ahead? if I read words from memory pointed by R1, for 16 times, I was supposed that the bytes ahead were 4*16=64. Why 128?

The same question with this example:

```
NEONCopyPLD
      PLD [r1, #0xC0]
      VLDM r1!,{d0-d7}
      VSTM r0!,{d0-d7}
      SUBS r2,r2,#0x40
      BGE NEONCopyPLD
```

Why 192 byte ahead if the Dn are 8 bytes each one and I load 8 registers each iteration?

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: The point of the preload hint is that memory is slow and takes a certain amount of time to read. Therefore you plan ahead by telling the CPU (via PLD) to start loading some memory ahead of where you are. By the time your processing loop catches up to that spot in memory, it has had enough time to read it into the cache.

Comment: This is clear for me, reading the documentation: why they wrote 128 byte ahead in a case and 192 in the other one? what is the best way to do this calculation? I was supposed in the first case 64 byte ahead. Where I wrong?

Comment: Your first example is 256 bytes ahead, but it's irrelevant. The 'offset' to use for preloading depends on the CPU, memory speed and what you're doing in your loop. You need to 'tune' it to the specific case by testing  values until you find the optimal one. It's hard to know ahead of time because each case is slightly different.

Comment: *what is the best way to do this calculation?* run the code with different values and time it.  It depends on the code, L1, L2 and DRAM speeds.  First order is that it gets to the L2 cache if present.  Note that caches have 'LINE sizes' so issuing PLD that is not a multiple of the line will pollute the instruction stream with garbage and can slow code.